# How to use em perfectly without getting nested issue?

Tags: css, xhtml

How to use `em` perfectly without getting nested issue?

How to get perfect needed size for every needed element?

If i use `#Wrapper (font-size:62.5%)` because it's easy to calculate font sizes.

How to deal with nested issues of `font-size` and `line-height`?

Comment: what's "needed element"?
how are you using em?
Please define "perfect" and the problem you are having.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, but http://www.loadaveragezero.com/vnav/labs/CSS/font-size.php has been useful to me. Or is that what you mean by “nested issue”?

Comment: You mean that relative font sizes of relative font sizes give counter-intuitive results?

Comment: I'm just echoing someone else said. Use `rem` if you want to avoid nested em issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*puts on flameshield*

I've been using the 62.5% + em method for 3 years but I just made the switch back to pixels.

Why?

- Pixels *are* a relative unit
- There's less and less IE6 users ( meaning more people are able to resize properly now and you don't have to worry about IE6's caveats as much )
- Modern browsers having better support for zoom in/out
- You save time - everyone understands pixels and there's no math involved in regards to inherited em font size and calculating relative to that

With that said:

- Do still use `pt` for printing because it's more reliable

If you still want to use ems that's fine. The best strategy, as counter-intuitive as it sounds is to make more specific rules so the em font size doesn't get inherited by everything.

Instead of:

```
body { font:62.5% arial; }
div#content { font-size:1.2em; }
p { font-size:0.9em; } /* have to calculate to try to get 11 px */
```

Do:

```
body { font:62.5% arial; }
div#content p { font-size:1.1em; }
```

Of course there exist utilities to do the pixel calculation for you ( an entire stylesheet or web page ) in ems but to me that's just a complete waste of time.

Comment: css3's CALC will fix most of these problems anyway.

Comment: -10. ;-) Pixels are not relative units. A pixel on a printer differs from a pixel on a screen.

Comment: @user257493 - Estimated time before practical usage: 10 years?

Comment: but what about mobile browsers?

Comment: hah! c'mon, it's only taken 4 years to get pretty-good support for CSS2! Split the difference? @user257493, let's use CSS3 in 7 years! See ya then!

Answer (score 3):

If you need to nest list elements (`li` tags), you can use the following CSS to make them not continue to grow or shrink:

```
li li {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sy92u/6/

Similar concepts can be applied to other situations, but may not work for your exact use-case.